# Combo Box in form not populating my table

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a form with a combo box (last name, first name, age, club) it works fine in the form but it will not work in my report or in my table it gives me the ID number instead of the information that is in the form.  What am I doing wrong?  I use Access 2010 but have had little training in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide that information in your query that is used to populate the report.  Reports in Access do not understand the same things the forms do.  If you need help creating the query let us know and we can help.